# show a pdf in 64 bit wpf application

Tags: wpf, pdf, adobe-reader

For a 32 bit wpf app if I want to show a pdf I usually use the following code:

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.Navigate(new Uri(filename));
grid1.Children.Add(browser);
```

And the adobe reader takes over and my pdf is show on screen.  The problem is I want to compile my application as AnyCPU so it will run in 64 bit mode on an x64 system.  So, on a 64 bit system the above code makes a 64 bit browser and the adobe reader plugin does not work in that, so the user gets a file download box.

Does anyone know of a way to show a pdf in a 64 bit wpf application?  I am open to 3rd party libraries, free or not. Or is there a way to make the WebBrowser run in 32 bit mode?

Thanks,

Comment: Just to confirm: you're sure your app really needs >2GB of address space? Not everyone understands the tradeoffs in making an app 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might check out the various [SDK tools from Foxit](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/sdk/). I can't say I've used their SDK tools before, but I've long used their PDF reader as an alternative to Adobe Reader.